# Best hardware+software to read UHF RFID tags?

Tags: hardware, rfid

I would like to sew in, UHF RDIF laundry tags into clothes and be able to read e.g. what do I have in my bag (i.e. multiple of them from up to 50 cm distance).

Here is example  set of such tags: [LAUNDRY TRACKING SAMPLE PACK - (PACK OF 20)](https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/laundry-tracking-sample-pack-pack-of-20/?utm_source=July_2016_Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Newsletter&utm_content=Product2ReadMore&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-_Gz02oq4BDPnizMYBwTAzTDHStIbmSXxwHFW97f1UrfAtajDbLQF21YSww_g_ibYE1zJuvpSg36ecx3H-VEnev27dOaA&_hsmi=31113402), their protocol seems to be:

```
Air Interface Protocol: EPCglobal UHF Class 1 Gen 2 (ISO 18000-6C)
Operating Frequency:   Global 860-960 MHz
IC Type: Monza 5
```

Do you have suggestion for reader I can connect to Raspberry Pi to read such tags programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [UHF RFID Reader](http://store.linksprite.com/long-range-uhf-rfid-reader-1-6m-iso18000-6c-epc-g2/) from Linksprite it is having RS232 output which you can connect with Raspberry Pi via [RS232 Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13029).

Answer (score -1):

You can buy any RFID reader on Alibaba as long as they have RS232 connection then buy RS232 shield for you Pi and use Pyserial to configure it and read the tags. If you need more support on the software I will edit my answer.